# Parsing ,error when insert into table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm getting error in my code while parsing and inserting to database 'a' is not defined.I am having a text file consisting of names and hobby.

qwer2.txt

```
My Name is Casssandra and my Hobby is Cooking.
My name is Archana and my hobby is Playing.Me Adarsh and my interest is Programming.Me Leela and my interest is Baking.My name is John and my interest is Gaming.
```

My program:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()
with open('qwer2.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if "My Name is" in line:
             a = line[line.index(key) + 1]
        if "hobby is" in line:
             b =  line[line.index(key) + 1]

        if "Me" in line:
             a = line[line.index(key) + 1]
        if "my interest" in line:
             b =  line[line.index(key) + 1]             
        cursor.execute('''INSERT into Details (Names, Hobby)
                          values (? , ?)'''%(a, b))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

I'm getting errors as 'a not defined/b not defined/key not defined'.I need to update database as Names and hobby in a row

Desired output:

```
Names      |  Hobby

Cassandra   Cooking  
Archana     Playing
Adarsh      Programming
Leela       Baking
John        Gaming
```

Please help!answers will be appreciated.

Comment: and where do you define `key`? The other one is more difficult, but `a` and `b` are not defined if none of the `if`s match.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need regular expression to parse the file. Based on your sample text file, I assume there are 2 different formats for each individual line. The following is a sample script to parse name and hobby.

```
import re

patterns = [
    re.compile('My name is (\w+) and my hobby is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
    re.compile('Me (\w+) and my interest is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
]

match_result = patterns[0].match(line) or patterns[1].match(line)
name, hobby = match_result.groups()
```

The `line` variable may not conform to the pattern. You should modify the regular expression patterns and do some error checking if needed.